# How to implement firebase cloud messaging in server side?

Tags: android, cron, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

After migrating to Firebase, i tested sending notification by using the firebase console it works fine, but i need a daily notification on a specific time so instead of using the firebase console i use my former cron job to send notification daily. I changed `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` but my device doesn't receive any notification.

Is there any way to solve this? Or did I miss anything? my cron job is working fine for my devices that is still using GCM.

Here's my code

```
function sendNotificationFCM($apiKey, $registrationIDs, $messageText,$id) {


    $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'Authorization:key=' . $apiKey
    );

    $message = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
            'data' => array(
                    "message" => $messageText,
                    "id" => $id,
            ),
    );


    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($message)
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: @McAwesomville from what i've read in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol it says that To send a message, the application server issues a POST request. For example: 'https.fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'

Comment: @McAwesomville its confusing on what to use :( but I'll try it.

Comment: I'll try to look around and let you know if ever I find something. :)

Comment: Btw, are you receiving any response from server?

Comment: It would seem that the way you are doing it is correct. Just not fully complete. Gonna remove my first comment to avoid future confusions.

Comment: @McAwesomville yes I'm receiving response from my server

Comment: @McAwesomville I added my code. Can you check what did I miss?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I added `notification` object in my json. 
I found out that in my `remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()` it returns null that's why it doesn't receive any notification send by my cron.

**Edit**

Here's my json object

```
$message = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
            'notification' => array(
                                    "title" => $id, 
                                    "body" => $messageText,
                                    "icon" => "name_of_icon" ),
            'data' => array(
                    "message" => $messageText,
                    "id" => $id,
            ),
    );
```

Comment: If it works, can you share the JSON object you're sending?

Comment: @Blacksad i added my json object

Comment: @mori Thanks a ton

Comment: i don't use curl. how can i implement server side in google endpoints clould module?

Comment: here what is 'name_of_icon'? is this http URL or assets path like `assets/images/icon.png`  Kindly suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Apart from changing the url to following:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

You also have to change the way you send request data:

```
 Content-Type:application/json
 Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

 {
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...", // "to" replaces "registration_ids" of gcm in fcm
   "data" : {
   ...
  },
}
```

Check out [this complete guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#format).

Comment: is `message_id` required?

Comment: No if you are working with `HTTP` requests only, yes if your implementing chat kind of functionality using `XMPP`.

Comment: I'm having an error `Field "to" must be a JSON string:`

Comment: as error stats `Field "to" must be a JSON string:`; the data you are sending in request wouldn't be a proper json. You can check it from some online json validator. If its proper things should work.

Comment: checking it on a json validator it says it is a valid json.

Comment: can I put multiple tokens inside `to`?

Comment: How can I get "to" for any device? Should I request to an api in app to get "to" for device?

Comment: You will receive unique device device id for each installed app, which you have to store on your server. Check this out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to comment directly in the selected answer. Take in consideration that the json message changes according to what you want/need to receive in the recipient os (android/ios).

e.g for android to get the notifications when the app is in background you need to add the *data* json in your request.

For iOS the data key is not needed, but you must have the *notification* key along with *isContentAvailble* flag set to true and priority set to high.

In the selected answer as valid, you use *registration_ids* key should be only used when you are sending the notification to more than one device, maybe you should take a look to the topics notifications.

Answer (score -2):

try use this :)

[Python client for FCM](https://github.com/olucurious/pyfcm)