# How to send notifications to the device when new post added to wordpress blog (flutter app)?

Tags: wordpress, api, flutter, notifications, push

I have a flutter app pulling posts through wordpress API ,  I want to auto send push notifications  to the flutter app when new post is published

any idea how can I achieve this?

I would be grateful if there is a tutorial to this.
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454822/how-to-implement-firebase-cloud-messaging-in-server-side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found How
By using this magnificent plugin (FCM Push Notification from WP) to send cloud message to firebase with the new post title and a pref of it with image display

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/fcm-push-notification-from-wp/
```

Then using firebase to send notification to devices with data as I said before, and it's working great till now
that's easiest way to do it.